# App icon displays on simulator but not on the real iphone

Tags: ios, icons, retina-display

As the title describes, I'm currently having an app icon issue,
I have 2 png, 1 is 57x57 Icon.png, another one is 114X114 Icon@2x.png
I store both of them under Supporting Files on xcode.
[image]

Here is how my  -Info.plist look like:
[image]

### and I also drag drop the app icon to target summary

[image]

### It display on simulator probably...

[image]

But not on my Real iphone5, it only displays as a white square on my iPhone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically do not try to rewrite the info.plist file. Here comes all the mess.
Avoid to modify it.

Solution :
pre: Delete all the icon files from the app summary (right click on the icon -> delete file)
1. delete app from simulator
2. Resert simulator 
3. Clean project CMD + Shift + K
4. Clean cahe CMD + Shift + ALT + K
5. Build project
6. Add new Icon
7. Try to upload on device

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the problem is the image file.

If you change a .jpg to a .png by modifying its extension, it shows well on the simulator but not on the real machine.

Try exporting .jpg as .png.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the cache. Try deleting the app, cleaning and running it again.

Comment: Did you clean your build folder? Hold down option then Product->Clean

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "Icon files" key in plist file, not "Icon files (iOS 5)"
2. Delete application from device
3. Clean your project in Xcode
4. Run app on device